# Bootstrap nav menu fixed bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I create a WP theme:

Code in header.php

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">

              <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => 4)); ?>

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When menu window is 980px climb up and down only is everything

I put an image to understand better

http://i61.tinypic.com/15heu55.jpg

How can be positioned down menu each time?

Comment: The code you posted seems fine, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/111/. Must be some other css that breaks that. Do you have any online version of your site?

Comment: yes..this is link http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/

Comment: avocat2.dac-proiect.ro...ops,sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to override the `position: static` to `position: fixed`.

Add this media query to the your style.css

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  margin-top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```